# BEP20 token not showing total supply as i entered on code on bscscan

Tags: binance-smart-chain, bep20

I have deployed a BEP20 token. I followed the steps shown in this tutorial https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/issue-BEP20.html
and I entered total supply = 60000000000 but after varifying, the total supply is not showing which was I entered. Can anyone help me to add the total supply? The contract address is 0xE2cFe49999e3a133EaFE13388Eb47BCd223f5c5E

Comment: Can you check the address and update the post with a correct one? The address that you shared [does not](https://bscscan.com/address/0xE25D3f12FcD303AeDc66dA9F931387e3A03e89e1) hold any contract on BSC.

Comment: Oo! sorry for that correct address is 0xE2cFe49999e3a133EaFE13388Eb47BCd223f5c5E

Answer (score 1):

Your token uses 18 decimal places. Which means that the value `60000000000` hardcoded on line 359 of your contract represents `0.00000006` of the token. The BSCScan [token tracker](https://bscscan.com/token/0xE2cFe49999e3a133EaFE13388Eb47BCd223f5c5E) shows total supply `0 AAG` just because it rounds to some predefined amount of decimals.

If you want a total supply of 60 billion, you need to add 18 zeros after this number to account for the decimals.

```
_totalSupply = 60000000000 * 1e18;
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer and my token is already deployed can you tell me how can I do this after deploy.. please explain me its really important for me

Comment: @Rohankumar I see that you published the `mint()` function that can be invoked only from the `owner` address. Which allows you to mint new tokens from this address, specifically you need to pass `59999999999999999940000000000` as the argument to get to the 60 billion total supply (with 18 decimals).

Comment: Thanx for your answer can help me for gaining more knowledge for deployment means can you suggest to me some tutorial about this or some online course where I can read?